# Stream Analytics job not outputting reliably

Tags: powerbi, azure-stream-analytics

My stream analytics job is getting data for last 24 hours

There is a lot of data to look at here, and whilst this worked for a while, its now stopped generating output events

This prevents data being sent to power bi

I only want the last 24 hours of data to be shown in Power BI

How can I do this?

I have tried to reduce the time window, but I dont want to do that as a fix.

```
SELECT [Timestamp], Broker, Price, COUNT(*)
INTO [powerbi2]
FROM [eventhubinput] TIMESTAMP BY [TimeStamp]
GROUP BY [TimeStamp], Broker, Price, TUMBLINGWINDOW(hh,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The query looks correct. There are a couple things that could be happening here:

1. Your `PowerBI` account is being throttled (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn950053.aspx) for limits on data ingress). If this is occurring, there should be warnings in your job's `Activity Log`. If this is the case, you may have to decrease the rate of your job's egress and/or upgrade your `PowerBI` account.
2. Your job is falling behind your `Event hub` due to the high rate of ingress. You can check this by looking at the `Input Events Backlogged` metric in the Portal. If this is the case, [scaling your job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-scale-jobs) may help.

If neither of these suggestions help, I'd recommend reaching out to Azure support so the team can take a closer look.